# How to add the ability to remove upvote or downvote on the second click?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-votable

Set my acts_as_votable, now the upvote and downvote buttons work properly but I want the user to remove his upvote on a second click like in facebook and twitter.
Here's my controller

```
 def upvote
      @post = Post.find
      @post.downvote_by current_user
  end

  def downvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.downvote_by current_user
  end
```

and the index

```
<%= link_to like_post_path(post), method: :put, class: 'upvote', remote: true  do %>
                    Upvote
                    <%= post.get_upvotes.size %>
                <% end %>

                <%= link_to dislike_post_path(post), method: :put, class: 'downvote', remote: true  do %>
                    Downvote
                    <%= post.get_downvotes.size %>
                <% end %>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<% unless post.liked_by current_user %>
<%= link_to like_post_path(post), method: :put, class: 'upvote', remote: true  do %>
     Upvote
     <%= post.get_upvotes.size %>
<% end %>
<% end %>

<% if post.liked_by current_user %>    
<%= link_to dislike_post_path(post), method: :put, class: 'downvote', remote: true  do %>
  Downvote
  <%= post.get_downvotes.size %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: still not working, the upvote button is now gone, and the downvote is not working